# Problems regarding meta titles

Tags: magento-1.7, multistore, meta-tags

We have problems regarding our meta titles on our Magento multi store.

**Website:** goo.gl/9W9hjQ

The multi store is running on one platform for both language.

**We started the languages in sub-categories as following:**

.com/en/

.com/da/

**But we decided to change it for TLDs, so our 2 language is now running on following TLDs (3-4 months ago):**

.co.uk

.dk

We have 301 redirected the old .com domain 1to1 to the .dk domain.

The meta titles is changed on the .dk domain as you can see in the browser. But Google is using the old meta titles from the .com domain.

Google is sometimes switching between the old and the new meta title in the SERP. The old meta titles is active 90% of time in the SERP. We are not able to see any problems with dmoz etc..

So is Google simply just confused, because of the .com redirect and will Google solve it over time?

Or is it a CMS/ Magento configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Have you uploaded new sitemap to Google? Sometimes it helps.

Comment: Yes, and it have been in the air for 2-3 months. Link: http://goo.gl/g7nZKE

Comment: I see some pages, like http://www.meandmet.dk/temaer/print-my-dress  have NOINDEX robot tag.  Is it on purpose?